# How to make Mac think I inserted a CD/DVD

Tags: mac, boot-camp, osx-mountain-lion

I'm setting up Boot Camp to install Windows.

I already created the bootable thumb drive via Boot Camp to install Windows, but I want to bypass the window that asks to insert a CD/DVD into the SuperDrive by making my Mac think a CD/DVD has been inserted.

How can I do that?

Comment: Just restart and hold down `option`.  You can select the Windows boot volume (assuming OSX allows it).  The only issue this way is that Mac doesn't repeatedly "bless" the drive to keep booting from that partition.  Though I think there is a terminal command to do that easily  (or in System Preferences > Boot Volume if it shows up yet).

Comment: Why would you need that? Why can't you install Windows through that thumb drive? Can you explain more about the actual problem you're trying to solve—not [the solution you thought of](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have to spoof the CD/DVD.  Took a quick look on [Google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=install%20windows%207%20from%20usb%20boot%20camp) and found [this site](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20020513-285/install-win-7-on-macbook-air-from-a-usb-drive/) which lays out how to install Windows 7 on a MacBook Air (not the same PC, but should be the same procedure).

It's also laid out in the [Boot Camp Noob's Guide](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/boot_camp_install-setup_10.7.pdf) (Warning: PDF).

Answer (score -1):

Daemon-Tools, some virtual DVD drive...should be able to allow BCA to begin partition.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. please refer to http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/179299 to learn how to recommend software properly on our community.

Comment: daemon tools will just made the iso prompt